# simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \X escape sequence u's': line 1 column 468 (char 467)

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests, imdb

I am having a problem while making an HTTP request to a REST api where my JSON formatted response isn't properly formed. There are escape sequences in the JSON which are interpreted correctly, but then there is a specific sentence which has the words "inner\spiritual", making the JSON decoder believe the "\s" is an escape sequence, when it is not meant to be.

Searching through the stackoverflow articles, I could not find a solution that fit my precise use case, but I figured out a good hack using the exceptions and indexing the JSON string and doing simple replacement. I thought it was worth a share since it might help someone in a similar situation. Happy hacking :)

**Full Code:**

```
import requests
import os
import json

base_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/'
tv_series = {}
films = {}

#for i in range(1, 9999999):
#imdb_id = 'tt' + str(i).zfill(7)
imdb_id = 'tt0120690'
print imdb_id



payload = {
            'i':imdb_id,
            'plot':'full',
            'r':'json'      
}
response = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
if response.status_code == 200:     
    result = None
    result = response.json()

    if result != None:
        if result['Response'] != 'False':
            if result['Type'] == 'movie':
                films[result['Title']] = result
            elif result['Type'] == 'series':
                tv_series[result['Title']] = result
            else:
                print '[ERROR] Type:', result['Type']
with open('tv_series.json', 'w') as tv_series_outfile:
    json.dump(tv_series, tv_series_outfile)

with open('films.json', 'w') as films_outfile:
    json.dump(films, films_outfile)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_imdb.py", line 41, in <module>
    result = response.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 797, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 127, in scan_once
    return _scan_once(string, idx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 93, in _scan_once
    _scan_once, object_hook, object_pairs_hook, memo)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 194, in JSONObject
    value, end = scan_once(s, end)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 90, in _scan_once
    return parse_string(string, idx + 1, encoding, strict)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 99, in py_scanstring
    raise JSONDecodeError(msg, s, end)
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \X escape sequence u's': line 1 column 468 (char 467)
```

Comment: `response.content.replace("\s","s")` would fix your example but the Api is broken, you may want to file a bug report

Comment: This is true, but not a generalized solution. It isn't ALWAYS `\s`. That is why I wrote a generalized solution to check WHERE the problem character lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Fix:**

```
def fix_JSON(json_message=None):
    result = None
    try:        
        result = json.loads(json_message)
    except Exception as e:      
        # Find the offending character index:
        idx_to_replace = int(e.message.split(' ')[-1].replace(')',''))      
        # Remove the offending character:
        json_message = list(json_message)
        json_message[idx_to_replace] = ' '
        new_message = ''.join(json_message)     
        return fix_JSON(json_message=new_message)
    return result
```

**Full Code:**

```
import requests
import os
import json


def fix_JSON(json_message=None):
    result = None
    try:        
        result = json.loads(json_message)
    except Exception as e:      
        # Find the offending character index:
        idx_to_replace = int(e.message.split(' ')[-1].replace(')',''))      
        # Remove the offending character:
        json_message = list(json_message)
        json_message[idx_to_replace] = ' '
        new_message = ''.join(json_message)     
        return fix_JSON(json_message=new_message)
    return result


base_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/'
tv_series = {}
films = {}
for i in range(1, 9999999):
    imdb_id = 'tt' + str(i).zfill(7)
    #imdb_id = 'tt0120690'
    print imdb_id



    payload = {
                'i':imdb_id,
                'plot':'full',
                'r':'json'      
    }
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:     
        result = None
        result = fix_JSON(json_message=response.content)

        if result != None:
            if result['Response'] != 'False':
                if result['Type'] == 'movie':
                    films[result['Title']] = result
                elif result['Type'] == 'series':
                    tv_series[result['Title']] = result
                else:
                    print '[ERROR] Type:', result['Type']
with open('tv_series.json', 'w') as tv_series_outfile:
    json.dump(tv_series, tv_series_outfile)

with open('films.json', 'w') as films_outfile:
    json.dump(films, films_outfile)
```